# Wireguard - LAN machine unpingable (Destination Host Unreachable) but DNS traffic reaches LAN PiHole/Unbound

Tags: wireguard

### Summary:

LAN address resolution works on some wireguard clients (my andorid phone) but not others (my linux laptop).

### Details:

I have wireguard running on two different Pi's (main and fail over - running on different ports) in my home network.

I setup both clients using PiVPN. Getting my phone hooked up is pretty much auto-magic with PiVPN's `-qr` option (I just change the DNS to my PiHole). Getting the surface it is more than likley have made some elementary error in the `.conf` file that I'm just blind too.

Each wireguard server has two clients:

1. My Android phone
2. My Microsoft Surface laptop/tablet (it's running Pop-OS 22.04 - shout-out to the surface-linux kernel project).

I funnel all of my Android phone's traffic through Wireguard 24/7 because one of those Pi's also runs a PiHole/Unbound combo for DNS. To avoid playing tech support for anyone other than myself I just point my machines at the local DNS server instead of setting it on the ISP router.

#### My LAN:

##### ISP router

- Static IP reservations for the Pis.
- Port forwarding on 51820 & 51821

##### boysen.homelab

- Wireguard (port 51821)

##### goose.homelab

- Pihole
- Unbound
- Wireguard (port 51820)

##### wg0.conf - Surface:

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = (redacted)
Address = 10.140.235.3/24,fd11:5ee:bad:c0de::3/64
DNS = 192.168.1.92 # My LAN PiHole's IP

[Peer]
PublicKey = <public key>
PresharedKey = (redacted)
Endpoint = my.personal.ddns.net:51820
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0, ::0/0
```

> aside: I have tried changing `AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0, ::0/0` to `AllowedIPs = 192.168.1.0/24` to no effect.

##### wg0.conf - Server:

This unfortunately is a place holder at the moment as I am away from home and the SSH keys for my various machines are on my surface not my phone (also doing terminal work on a touchscreen is torture).

I've tried tethering my surface to my phone to try to pass my traffic through to the LAN in order to get an SSH connection but for some reason my tehtered traffic doesn't appear to be getting passed to the wireguard interface.

##### The issue

My phone is able to resolve IPs of machines inside my LANs but my surface tablet is not
**BUT**
my surface is able to pass DNS traffic to the pihole (confirmed via PiHole admin console, `tcpdump` and dnsleaktest.org) through wireguard which I set in `wg0.conf` via my LAN IP. The fact that the DNS traffic is making it through the PiHole in my LAN but can't ping a device quite confusing.

Trying to ping any of the machines in my LAN on the surface looks like this:

```
stenolepis@pop-os:~$ ping 192.168.1.92
PING 192.168.1.92 (192.168.1.92) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.1.89 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.89 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.89 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
```

If I try to connect to any of the services running in my LAN via browser I get this:
[browser_unable_to_connect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKbcY.png)

This looks very similar to the ["Destination Address Required" mentioned in the Ubuntu Wireguard Troubleshooting doc](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/wireguard-vpn-troubleshooting) only I don't get `ping: sendmsg: Destination address required`.

I think it's a routing issue because if I run:

```
stenolepis@pop-os:~$ sudo ip route get 192.168.1.92
192.168.1.92 dev wlp1s0 src 192.168.1.89 uid 0 
    cache
```

It does not appear to be routing to the wireguard interface and I do not understand why.

Clearly there is a subnet collision with the network I am on and my home LAN (both using 192.168.1.x) but if wireguard is setup to take all my traffic I don't see why this would be a problem and more so why it wouldn't affect my phone as well.

Or I am fooling myself as my network debugging skills are limited.

Additional troubleshooting:

Result of `ip a` with wg0 up:

```
stenolepis@pop-os:~$ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: virbr0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:a2:c4:09 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.122.1/24 brd 192.168.122.255 scope global virbr0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlp1s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 28:16:a8:51:52:82 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.70/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp1s0
       valid_lft 84617sec preferred_lft 84617sec
    inet6 2001:569:70d6:d700:568c:4fcf:4983:1bd5/64 scope global temporary dynamic 
       valid_lft 14682sec preferred_lft 14382sec
    inet6 2001:569:70d6:d700:ecfe:8f0d:350f:414e/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 14682sec preferred_lft 14382sec
    inet6 fe80::6bd3:60c3:353b:c5d0/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
14: wg0: <POINTOPOINT,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1420 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/none 
    inet 10.140.235.3/24 scope global wg0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fd11:5ee:bad:c0de::3/64 scope global 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Comment: `It does not appear to be routing to the wireguard interface and I do not understand why.` - perhaps because wireguard is not connected - what's the result of `ip a`

Comment: Not connected in any particular way? The handshake seems to be going through without an issue along with my DNS queries.
I have appended the result of `ip a` to the bottom of the original post.

Comment: I suggested it because your route to the wiregurad interface (your words)

Answer (score 0):

This is your core problem:

> there is a subnet collision with the network I am on and my home LAN (both using 192.168.1.x)

On some platforms, like Android, if you set `AllowedIPs` to everything (eg `0.0.0.0/0` and/or `::/0`), the WireGuard client will automatically override all of the host's routes to route everything (except its own encrypted packets) out the WireGuard interface.

But on Linux, the WireGuard client script [wg-quick](https://git.zx2c4.com/wireguard-tools/about/src/man/wg-quick.8) works very hard to avoid overriding all but the host's default route when `AllowedIPs` is set to everything.

If you run `ip route show table main` on your Pop!_OS tablet when it's running on your non-home LAN with its WireGuard interface up, you'll see something like this:

```
$ ip route show table main
default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlp1s0 proto dhcp src 192.168.1.70 metric 100
10.140.235.3/24 dev wg0 scope link
169.254.0.0/16 dev wlp1s0 scope link metric 1000
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlp1s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.70 metric 100
192.168.122.0/24 dev virbr0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.122.1
```

All of the routes listed in your main routing table (except the default route) will be used in preference to the default route that the wg-quick script sets up. So when you try to connect to any host in the `192.168.1.0/24` network, like your Pi at `192.168.1.92`, the connection will be routed out your `wlp1s0` interface to the gateway of whatever LAN you're on -- not out your WireGuard interface.

The wg-quick script will set up a new default route in a custom `51820` routing table:

```
$ ip route show table 51820
default dev wg0 scope link
```

And the wg-quick script will set up a few policy routing rules to define when to use this custom `51820` routing table -- using it to override just the default route from the main table:

```
$ ip rule list
0:  from all lookup local
32764:  from all lookup main suppress_prefixlength 0
32765:  not from all fwmark 0xca6c lookup 51820
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default
```

If want you to override all the routes from your main routing table, and not just the default route, you need to add a different policy routing rule when the `wg0` interface is up:

```
$ sudo ip rule add not fwmark 51820 table 51820 priority 123
```

This rule directs the system to use the custom `51820` table for everything -- except when the packet mark has been set to `51820` (`0xca6c` in hex). WireGuard will set this packet mark on all the encrypted packets it sends out -- and those packets need to use the main routing table so they can be sent to the LAN gateway and forwarded on to the Internet.

You can make the wg-quick script automatically add and remove this rule when it starts up and shuts down the `wg0` interface by adding the following PreUp/PostDown scripts to the `[Interface]` section of the `wg0.conf` file:

```
PreUp = ip rule add not fwmark 51820 table 51820 priority 123
PostDown = ip rule del not fwmark 51820 table 51820 priority 123
```